# How to stop user post Adult Content URL

Tags: html, url

I built a form where user post urls of different categories of website. I did some validation that user only post url at right format. I also want to filter the adult urls or i want to stop the user to not post Adult urls. For submit the form there is no login or logout options. No signup required to post the urls. Any idea how to do this .?

Comment: This is a very broad question that has many solutions, and is probably not appropriate as a SO question. You may want to look at websites which provide URL categorization APIs. Also, I'd suggest adding a captcha if not done already.

Comment: Thanks captcha i will do it. could you please specify few best apis for url filtering?

Comment: See this similar question, which has some recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083578/safe-site-api-detect-whether-a-site-has-adult-fraud-or-malicious-content

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you use if statements to check if user codes content words like **porn**, **xxx**, **pornhub** etc...
you need a lot of listing if you you actually want to do it my way.

Comment: Bad idea. There are a lot of porn sites without such identifiable keywords, and also a lot of genuine sites with these keywords.

Comment: yes thats the problem. Its very hard to write thousands of website in if statements also new websites came everyday.. Any better  solution .?

Comment: yah, one can't guarantee it. So i think it is good to at least prevent the popular words/names known

Comment: Actually no. You can't block even seemingly straightforward, "popular words" like porn or xxx. I don't know OP's exact usecase, but there could be a store called "KP Ornaments" which sells jewelry. If they have a site it could be kpornaments . com, which would be blocked by your logic. As for xxx, there's a famous Hollywood movie by that name and sites associated with it could get blocked. These are just a few small examples.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments. I will try some of these things now. I don't know which answer is right so i should open this unless someone might post something new later.